# What do I study to find another description of this subset of the rationals?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, rational-numbers

Highway signs in the US generally depict the distance to several of the nearest exits, generally in whole numbers, or in quarter- or half-miles:

[image]

Inspired by this observation, I started thinking about fractions that could be represented using only the (base-ten) digits $1$ through $4$. In particular, I thought: Suppose $H$ is the set of positive integers with this type of expansion, and $Q_H$ is the set of rationals equivalent to $a / b$ where $a$ and $b$ are in $H$.

After playing around with the set, I've discovered that (for example) $\frac{1}{5}$ is not in $Q_H$, since for all $k$, $5k$ is congruent to either $5$ or $0$ mod $10$. Similarly $\frac{1}{9}$ is not, since when $k$ is in $H$ (and therefore congruent to $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$ mod $10$), $9k$ is congruent to $9$, $8$, $7$, or $6$. ($\frac{2}{9} = \frac{32}{144}$, however, is in $Q_H$).

But I'd like to find another way to characterize the (positive) rationals in, or not in, $Q_H$.

I *did* get a BA in theoretical mathematics 25 years ago, but I don't remember taking any course where we discussed questions like this; so I don't even know where to start—or for that matter what I need to know in order to get to where I need to start. Is this, for example, a number theory question? Where should I start looking to get the skills I need to try and answer this?

Comment: I'm afraid you're very likely to be disappointed.  Questions that involve digit structure tend to (a) not be considered 'serious mathematics' for the most part, and (b) tend to be inordinately difficult to study, because they're almost entirely independent of essentially all the tools that have been developed. For instance, your sets aren't closed under multiplication ($\frac13\times\frac13=\frac19$, and $\frac19\times\frac19=\frac1{81}=\frac4{324}$ or under addition ($\frac1{12}+\frac4{144}=\frac19$ and $\frac19+\frac19=\frac29$) which means they have very little 'amenable' structure.

Comment: Contrast this with, for instance, the set of _dyadic_ rationals $\mathbb{Q}_D = \{\frac a{2^d}\}$, which is a group, about which many things can be said, and which in turn touches on various rather deep facets of mathematics.

Comment: That is disappointing. I suppose I could "just find something different to wonder about" but it's very disappointing to find an interesting (to me) apparently obviously mathematical question and then realize that there's literally nowhere to go with it.

Comment: Some ideas for where to start. First: As you've started to see, the set of positive integers $I$ whose *last* digit is 1, 2, 3, or 4 is relatively easy to reason about. So try characterizing $Q_I$ instead. If you can solve that problem, then it may help to tackle $Q_H$. Second: Instead of base ten, try using a prime base like three or five. That should also simplify matters. Third: If you're stuck, throw a computer at the problem. Try to compute some fragment of $Q_I$ by brute force; find a way to visualize the result; and look for patterns.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Thanks! :-) :-) I'll start with base 5 maybe.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I would be glad to mark that as an accepted answer and give you some credit if you want to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas for where to start...

As you've started to see, the set of positive integers $I$ whose last digit is 1, 2, 3, or 4 is relatively easy to reason about. So try characterizing $Q_I$ instead. If you can solve that problem, then it may help to tackle $Q_H$.

Instead of base ten, try using a prime base like three or five. That should also simplify matters.

If you're stuck, throw a computer at the problem. Try to compute some fragment of $Q_I$ by brute force; find a way to visualize the result; and look for patterns.